# Index of queries which returned value

Tags: sql, union

I have multiple queries builded from one schema, simple e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE someparam = 'paramvalue1' UNION
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE someparam = 'paramvalue2' UNION ...
```

Queries are created by switching someparam value. Of course I'm able to change all the queries with sql IN operator and it should work the same way. But the thing is I need numbers of all queries, which gave me any results. So if queries with param value "paramvalue2" and "paramvalue5" returned me a result, then I want some column, e.g. "results" with values [2,5].
What is the simplest way to do it? I need a solution that will work on PostgreSQL, MSSQL and Oracle.

EDIT:
I don't wanna mess with my schema query, which is e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE someparam = ?
```

That's just simple example, query can have multiple parameters and JOINS etc., I just wanna work on simple example.

The result I want to get is number of query, which gave me any result at all, I don't need any values. The solution given by @Jasen is almost fine, cause the only change I need to do is replace "SELECT" with "SELECT  as results,". I wonder if it can be done without interfering in my query at all.

Comment: I don't understand why after using 'IN' for your someparam column won't give you the desired values in someparam column?

Comment: Please can you edit your question to include the expected output of your query. E.g. are you looking for counts? A list of the distinct parameters returned by your query? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
SELECT 1 AS queryno,* FROM some_table WHERE someparam = 'paramvalue1' 
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS queryno, * FROM some_table WHERE someparam = 'paramvalue2' 
UNION ALL...
```

OTOH in the above you could just look at the value of `someparam` in the result.

I'm using `UNION ALL` because by adding queryno there will be bo shared rows, and using `UNION ALL` skips the de-duping step.

Comment: `UNION ALL` would be more efficient in this case

Comment: yeah, i paused editing that in to watch a car chase on telly :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how to make it work on all those DBs, but you can do something along the lines of

```
select x.id, some_table.* from
sme_table join 
(select 1 as id, 'paramvalue1' as val UNION
 select 2, 'paramvalue2' UNION
 select 3, 'paramvalue3' UNION
 select 4, 'paramvalue4'
 ...
) x on sme_table.someparam = x.val
```

you can get the results vector using `GROUP_CONCAT(x.id)` or its equivalent in the DB of choice.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but it won't work for me - my query needs to remain as it is, I mean this part: 

SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE someparam = ?

That's because I'm getting query from unknown source, so I need to handle almost any query. 
I can add something before and treat it like a subquery, but I can not modify it.

Comment: You mean you need to pass an unknown number of parameters in? Why not `select * from some_table where someparam in (....)` where the list of parameters is inside the brackets? Or are you saying that the "sometable" could be different tables, rather than all the same table?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way would be to use the DENSE_RANK() analytic function, which should be a lot more efficient than querying the same table multiple times, e.g.:

```
WITH some_table AS (SELECT 1 ID, 100 val, 'paramvalue1' someparam FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 2 ID, 200 val, 'paramvalue2' someparam FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 3 ID, 300 val, 'paramvalue3' someparam FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 4 ID, 400 val, 'paramvalue1' someparam FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 5 ID, 500 val, 'paramvalue2' someparam FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 6 ID, 600 val, 'paramvalue6' someparam FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 7 ID, 700 val, 'paramvalue5' someparam FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 8 ID, 800 val, 'paramvalue2' someparam FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 9 ID, 900 val, 'paramvalue3' someparam FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 10 ID, 1000 val, 'paramvalue1' someparam FROM dual)
SELECT dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY someparam) results,
       st.*
FROM   some_table st
WHERE  someparam IN ('paramvalue1', 'paramvalue2', 'paramvalue3', 'paramvalue4', 'paramvalue5')
ORDER BY 1;

   RESULTS         ID        VAL SOMEPARAM
---------- ---------- ---------- -----------
         1          4        400 paramvalue1
         1          1        100 paramvalue1
         1         10       1000 paramvalue1
         2          2        200 paramvalue2
         2          5        500 paramvalue2
         2          8        800 paramvalue2
         3          9        900 paramvalue3
         3          3        300 paramvalue3
         4          7        700 paramvalue5
```